# Automatic distribution of Java update

Tags: java, auto-updates

Is there a solution like WSUS for windows, where the update can be pushed automatically to all the systems in the network and install without the user requiring to enter Admin credentials? Currently all users call the IT help-desk to do the necessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called patch management software.  There are countless patch management software solutions out there.  Google [patch management software](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=5V5-rhqXYzwK_-Ug6BJKMw&cp=25&gs_id=36&xhr=t&q=patch+management+software&es_nrs=true&pf=p&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&sclient=psy-ab&oq=patch+management+software&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44990110,d.dmg&fp=ae6c4f3295ad3943&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=815) and you will see a huge list.  Things to consider when purchasing are price, platforms supported, whether its agent/agentless, what non-microsoft products they support, can you create custom packages, reporting, etc.  This is a pretty hefty topic and you should definitely do some research.

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute the Java software via Group Policy in your domain. All you need is the MSI installer file for the latest Java software.

Basically the installer already contains the necessary MSI file which can be extracted: http://www.klaus-hartnegg.de/gpo/msi_java.html